# Extjs add component or remove all and load anew

Tags: extjs

I'm new to Extjs and I would like to ask about adding new component to a viewport. Which way will be better: (a) add a new component to what's already there or (b) remove all and load everything, including the new component? In terms of coding (difficulty to write, readability, maintenance) and performance. And if it depends on the situation, may you elaborate on which method is most suitable in which situation? Thank you.

Comment: That entirely depends on the situation.

Comment: Which situation calls for which? Thanks